# Module parse failed: Unexpected token (89:16) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. | columnNumber: 29 | } > },

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm

When I run npm start command I get this error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/layouts/CheckoutAndReviewBox.tsx 89:16  Module parse failed: Unexpected token (89:16)  You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.  
|       columnNumber: 29  
|     } 
|    }, props.book?.copies, " "), "copies"), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("p", {  
|     className: "col-6 lead",  
|  __self: _this,
```

This is my CheeckoutandReviewBox.tsx file

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import BookModel from "../models/BookModel";

export const CheckoutAndReviewBox: React.FC<{ book: BookModel | undefined, mobile: boolean, }> = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className={props.mobile ? 'card d-flex mt-5' : 'card col-3 container d-flex mb-5'}>
            <div className='card-body container'>
                <div className='mt-3'>
                    <p>
                        <b>0/5 </b>
                        books checked out
                    </p>
                    <hr />
                    {props.book && props.book.copiesAvailable && props.book.copiesAvailable > 0 ?
                        <h4 className='text-success'>
                            Available
                        </h4>
                        :
                        <h4 className='text-danger'>
                            Wait List
                        </h4>
                    }
                    <div className='row'>
                        <p className='col-6 lead'>
                            <b>{props.book?.copies} </b>
                            copies
                        </p>
                        <p className='col-6 lead'>
                            <b>{props.book?.copiesAvailable} </b>
                            available
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <Link to='/#' className='btn btn-success btn-lg'>Sign in</Link>
                <hr />
                <p className='mt-3'>
                    This number can change until placing order has been complete.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Sign in to be able to leave a review.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

In my earlier code, I attempted numerous Webpack loaders, but none of them were successful. When I searched for the problem, many posts claimed that it was a typescript or tsconfig problem.

Is there a fix for this?